# Firebase RealTime Rules

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

my app have an admin panel, and i would like to set firebase rules so that only admin are allowed to put new products or items in certain firebase.Child

i want the only users from the child("Admins") would be allowed to write into other categories like Work, private, video, so how to make a child from a reference like Admins only be able to access other children ?

this is my current firebase-RealTime Rules.

```
  {
  "rules": {
    "Admins": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    },
    "Users": {
        ".read": true,
            ".write": true,
          ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'phoneNumber', 'uid'])",
          "name": {".validate": true},
          "phoneNumber": {".validate": true},
          "uid": {".validate": true},
          "$other": {".validate": false}
    },
    "PrivateWork": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": false
    },
    "Likes": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null"
    },
    "Work": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": false
    },
    "videos": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow admins global write access, you can add a single top-level rule like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": "root.child('Admins').child(auth.uid).exists()",
    "Admins": {
      ...
```

Since [permission cascades downwards](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#read_and_write_rules_cascade), this will also grant them access on all child nodes.

Comment: Thanks. As expected, you always answer fast ,  another small question if possible is it right way to make the read of "Users" child to be true , i tried to make it auth.uid != null so only authorized can see user info, but if i did so i won't be able to Login since there is not Auth before Login

Comment: Logging in is a call to Firebase Authentication, so that should. not fail based on a rule in your database. If you're having trouble making it work, I recommend posting a separate question with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: true i can login but i can't reg new users

Comment: i just tried it and it didn't work firebase still gives me permission denied error, is it because i overwrite the rules, after each child by saying false?

Comment: Permission cascades downwards. Once you grant a user read permission at the root, they can read the entire database. There's now way to revoke that. If the user does not have permission, they are either not signed in yet when you try to read from the database, or their UID is not stored as a key in the `Admins` node.

Comment: i have updated my question Firebase Image, please check

Comment: Those keys under Admins are not UIDs. The security rule can't execute a query, so you **must** use the UID as the key there. The value doesn't matter, since I use `exists` in the rules, but they key has to be the UID.

Comment: true, thanks now i understand